# My goal is to make b constant so while true, it will continue adding b to the list throughout the loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, random, python-requests

I want user input in b to constantly be in the loop

```
while True:
     a = ["apple", "banana", "cherry"]
     b = [input("enter fruits: ")]
     a.extend(b)
     print(a)
```

Comment: what do you mean by repeat itself, could you give us a sample input with an expected output?

Answer (score 3):

You have to get "a" out of the loop so that "a" won't be apple, banana and cherry every single iteration.
And changing the variable name to fruits would make your code more readable.
Try this:

```
fruits = ["apple", "banana", "cherry"]    
while True:
    new_fruit = input("enter fruits: ")
    fruits.extend(new_fruit)
    print(fruits)
```

if you want to print every single item of this list then you can do this:

```
for fruit in fruits:
    print(fruit)
```